# Solaris linker verbosity options (ld -D tokens)

Tags: linker, solaris

When linking with `ld` (SunOS 5.10, Sun Studio 12), what is the list of possible tokens that are accepted by `ld -D`?

Neither `man ld` nor `ld --help` reveals the proper list. Namely, I need full information on the missing symbols (not just the demangled name of a C++ function).

Comment: Presumably you mean SunOS 5.10 (aka Solaris 10), since SunOS 5.1 (Solaris 2.1) has been obsolete for over a decade, and could never run a compiler as new as Sun Studio 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the man page says:

```
     -D token,...

         Prints  debugging  information,  as  specified  by  each
         token,  to  the  standard error.  The special token help
         indicates the full list of tokens available.
```

running `ld -D help` does indeed output the list of available options.

Comment: Indeedy do. I misunderstood the man, thinking there is a special help on tokens, instead of a token called 'help'. Thanks.